# What is the best way to handle destruction of objects in C#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

I have a Class Library project which has a class that creates a file during object construction. The file has to be deleted when the object is done. I have implemented [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and written the Delete code in Dispose(). The issue is, I still see the file. I remember reading somewhere that [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not guaranteed to be called. What would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Have you looked into the `using` keyword at all?

Comment: Please show your code (and exception that is thrown when you are trying to `Delete` file that is still in use).

Comment: Cannot use using, The lifetime of the object is indefinite. I am not saying delete is throwing exception, My code to delete is never called.

Comment: If it was for C++, I would simply delete file in destructor, call delete on the object if it was declared in heap or do nothing if it was in stack. But in C#, I am not sure how wrapping up occurs.

Answer (score 5):

Best practice in .NET is to use the `using` block.  I would expect that you cannot guarantee that your code will always be GC'd if someone writes code that orphans it; however

### [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.
>
> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

```
using(YourDisposable iCanDispose = new YourDisposable())
{

  // work with iCanDispose
}
```

Will ensure that the objects dispose method is called once it has left scope.

Comment: My object's lifetime is unknown. It is created and kept alive until user closes the application.

Answer (score 2):

The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword is your friend in this case.  Anything that implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can use it, and it gives you a better mechanism to ensure your objects are disposed.

It's usage looks something like this:

```
using (SomeIDisposableObject someThing = new SomeIDisposableObject())
{
   // Do some work here and don't sweat to much because once I fall out-of-scope
   // I will be disposed of.
}
```

You can also nest them, like so:

```
using (SomeIDisposableObject someThing = new SomeIDisposableObject())
{
   // I am next up for being disposed of.
   using (SomeOtherIDisposableObject someOtherThing = new SomeOtherIDisposableObject())
   {
      // I will get disposed of first since I am nested.
   }
}
```

You can also stack them:

```
using (SomeIDisposableObject someThing = new SomeIDisposableObject())
{
   // I will be disposed of.
}

using (SomeOtherIDisposableObject someOtherThing = new SomeOtherIDisposableObject())
{
   // I will also be disposed of.
}
```

Comment: you don't have to nest them either, you can stack them without creating nests.

Comment: @Mike McMahon - Yes, that is correct (and I forgot about that).  Thanks for the reminder; I will edit the answer to incorporate an example of it.

Answer (score 2):

you can call Dispose() function on any object (which implements the IDisposable Interface) inside the finally block to guarantee the object distruction.

using block can be used to simplify the above solution without creating try and finally blocks. so any object which needs to use using() block should implement IDisposable Interface  so that object will be Disposed immediately ,as soon as it comes out of using block.

using syntax:

```
using(object declaration and initialization)
{
//statements
}
```

the using block is similar to following:

```
try
{
//object declaration and initialization
}
finally
{
//Call Object's Dispose() 
}
```

Comment: You can also do this using a `Destructor` too.